# how to ensure a required cue library is in the import list when generating a cue schema file

Tags: go, cuelang

#### Env

```
cue version

cue version v0.6.0

go version go1.20.6
      -buildmode exe
       -compiler gc
       -trimpath true
     CGO_ENABLED 0
          GOARCH arm64
            GOOS darwin
```

#### Question

How can I make sure when I generate a cue schema file from a Golang module that a requisite cuelang library is in the import list? Rather than having to manually add it in each time at the top of the cue schema file.

#### Example

With a golang module, `app.go`

```
package kasl

import (
    "cuelang.org/go/cue"
    "cuelang.org/go/pkg/list"
    "github.com/my-org/pkg/route"
)

func existsOnlyForImportReasons(a []cue.Value) bool {
    return list.UniqueItems(a)
}

type App struct {
    Apps                    []AppV1               `yaml:"apps"`
        ...
```

I can generate the following cue schema file via `cue get go app.go` which yields

```
package app

import "github.com/my-org/pkg/route"

#SpecV1: {
    apps: [...#AppV1] @go(Apps,[]AppV1)
```

Why doesn't the above cue schema file, `app_gen_go.cue`, have the following as its import list? I have to manually add `"list"` each time otherwise the constraints in the file that do use `list` throw errors.

```
import (
         "list"
         
        "github.com/my-org/pkg/route"
)
```